# Why isn't login forensics available on government pods?

Tags: security, login, spring16, login-forensics

Not that I work on a government pod, but I'm curious. I read this in the [Spring'16 release notes](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_monitoring_login_forensics.htm). Why on earth would Salesforce keep this feature from a sys admin on a government pod? I'd like to know when login attempts are being made from Chinese IP addresses!

Comment: what exact information you are looking for?

Comment: Nothing specific, I'm just curious.

Comment: Did you check login history under user details page ?  I think that give sufficient information to track down.

Comment: That is not my question. I want to know why some sys admins do not have the same capabilities as other sys admins, based on their pod. Why are commercial/corporate sys admins allowed more insight than government sys admins?

Comment: @SanderdeJong -thanks for the question. First thing to understand is that  Login Forensics is based on Login History. It's the same schema and data capture.  The primary difference is the data retention period. This is analogous to Field History Tracking and Field Audit Trail. Same schema, different data retention period.

Comment: @SanderdeJong - So the reason why Login Forensics is not supported on government pod is because of the added retention capabilities which involves hardware that is not yet supported on that pod. However, to address your original question: "I'd like to know when login attempts are being made from Chinese IP addresses" - you can use login history *and* login geo sobjects for isolating login IPs.